# Facebook google authentication for android application using django

Tags: android, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest social auth for token based authentication(djangorestrframework-jwt), the link for same is https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth. In the example it is using satelizer(angular's end to end token based authentication module) at front end for the middleware work, however I am building an android application with backend on drf and I am stuck because of this. Can anyone help me with any module for android which does the work like satelizer in angular or should I choose a different social auth for this purpose instead of using rest social auth.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a combination of `django-rest-framework` along with [python-social-auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/), [django-oauth-toolkit](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2)

`django-oauth-toolkit` implements Oauth2 protocol and provides the access token based authentication/authorization for your clients (ie. angular app, android app)

`python-social-auth` takes care of fetching user details from Facebook/Google and creating a User object.

`django-rest-framework-social-oauth2` will act as a glue between `django-oauth-toolkit` and `python-social-auth`. It basically provides an endpoint which takes in access-token provided by Facebook/Google and returns `django-oauth-toolkit's` access token which will be used to make authenticated requests to DRF.

[This](https://yeti.co/blog/summary-drf-oauth-and-social-authentication/) 4 part blog series will help you in working with all of the above mentioned packages (except `django-rest-framework-social-oauth2`)

If you set up things on backend (ie. Django project) the way shown in that blog series, you won't need any external module/package on your clients (ie. angular app/android app)

Comment: Thanks Amrullah, I ended up using the combination of all as you suggested. I have used django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 for the same and I don't have to use external package anymore, however for the conver-token method, which converts fb/g+ token to application token, how can I add that on post save method, so that it creates a new token for every user created. I looked at this post(https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/31) but I am not sure how to make a call to convert-token post save. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user2689193: I suggest calling `/convert-token/` end-point from your clients. If you take a look at signature of `oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.tokens.BearerToken.create_token()` method, you'll notice that it takes an HttpRequest object as a mandatory parameter. Which means if you try to create an AccessToken for user in `post_save` signal, you'll have to create and supply a mock `HttpRequest` object (which although, is possible through `django.test.client.RequestFactory`, but is it worth the effort?). 

Or may be, you can use [requests] (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package ...

Comment: @user2689193: ... to make http request to `/convert-token/` end-point. ( **Caution:** I am not sure whether that will always work).

Can you explain me, why are you trying to generate `AccessToken` object in `post_save` signal? Is that some sort of compulsion?

Comment: Its not compulsion as such, I wanted one api for the login from client, which will check if user exists and if not create one and return the token converted. I want to avoid the convert-token call from client side. I ended up writing custom code for token generation at client side and assigning it to user in the python-social-auth user access token.